# LibreOffice on FreeBSD (GhostBSD) is missing GnuPG encryption entry fields

Tags: freebsd, gpg, libreoffice

I set up a FreeBSD 14 (GhostBSD) box with a complete set of my GnuPG keys. Encryption/Decryption on the cli works as expected.

I am used to encrypt files within LibreOffice on Linux (on the same machine) and Windows. But in the installation (from the binaries not the ports collection) on Ghost BSD (version 24.2.0.3 X86_64) the control panel "User data" (German: "Benutzerdaten") lacks the entries for signing and en-/decryption with OpenPGP.
gpg has version 2.4.4., libgcrypt 1.10.3.

How can I get this feature also on GhostBSD?

Answer (score 1):

The `pkg` binary packages are made from `ports` with default settings. My initial reaction was that LibreOffice probably was not compiled with that option and you would need to go to ports and do a `make config`.

That does however not seem to be the case when we look at [editors/libreoffice/](https://www.freshports.org/editors/libreoffice/) as we do not see anything directly PGP related. You can get the same info with the command `pkg info libreoffice`.

It is however interesting to note that:

```
...
GNOME=off: GNOME desktop environment support
GTK3=off: GTK 3 GUI toolkit support
GTK4=off: GTK+ 4 GUI toolkit support (experimental, broken)
...
```

GhostBSD by default uses MATE and GTK. I am then unsure if GhostBSD is using the standard `libreoffice` package. You can verify exactly what packages are installed with `pkg info`.

I see no mention of it in the GhostBSD documentation but if my memory is correct then GhostBSD is using the default FreeBSD package repositories. You can verify that by looking in `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/` (and `/etc/pkg/*.conf`. This is documented in [pkg-repository](https://man.frebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pkg-repository) but is fairly obvious when you look in the files.

But apart from that tangent we turn to [LibreOffice PGP](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/openpgp.html) and it seems that it should automatically find the PGP libraries if available.

A little searching does however reveal that this is not a [uncommon problem](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/openpgp-in-lo6/30684/10). In the thread no-one comes up with a solution but a couple of ideas worth pursuing:

1. It seems that `gpgme` has some hardcoded path assumptions when looking for the initial `gpg.conf` file. On FreeBSD that would most likely be somewhere in `/usr/local/etc`. A quick workaround could then be doing a link from `/etc` to match the likely expected location (by LibreOffice).
2. The last entry states:

> No key is the only option available when I open Libreoffice as an Admin user. However, when I execute Libreoffice from terminal as a super user I am able to access the keys…

This makes me suspect a permissions problem. Or maybe more likely a difference in how the environment (path) is setup.

So no definitive answer from me but at least some ideas on where to look. It seems that LibreOffice is not good enough at automatically detecting a proper PGP installation.

Comment: I followed the suggested steps above (thx!). gpgme is installed. The pkg info gave same results as quoted. Besides, the repos seem to be now "really" GhostBSD-ish (no link to FreeBSD), plus there was no gpg.conf in /usr/local/etc. Then I didn't find a gpg.conf, but I compared the installation with my Fedora box. I first added a common.conf to my ~/.gnupg-directory with the same entry (use-keyboxd). I found a gpgconf.conf in both /usr/share/doc/gnupg2/examples (Fedora) and /usr/local/share/* (GhostBSD) which is not in use. Unfortunately no results.

Comment: If [gpgme](https://www.freshports.org/security/gpgme/) is installed I am out of suggestions. If I can find the time after easter I will see if I can reproduce on FreeBSD.

Comment: That would be so great! I will now switch into OpenIndiana which doesn't have that issue in their LibreOffice. And I try to analyse the installation and compare it to GhostBSD.